# How do I reference a field name that contains a dot in mustache template?

Tags: template-engine, mustache

How do I reference a field name that contains a dot in mustache template?  For instance, if I have a view like

```
{
  "foo.bar": "my value"
}
```

then how can I put `my value` into a template? Using `{{foo.bar}}` doesn't work because mustache thinks the dot is part of the path, like there should be a "foo" that has a "bar".

Comment: It would be easier to refactor the property to `foo_bar`. Not a solution?

Comment: heh, I found this problem after 10 years and it's still not fixed!

Answer (score 7):

You can't read a key with a `.` in it from Mustache. The Mustache spec dictates that `.` is used to split content names. Mustache provides a means of escaping but only for HTML content.

Mustache spec: [interpolation](https://github.com/mustache/spec/blob/master/specs/interpolation.yml#L7)

You will need to pre-process your data to make it usable in a Mustache template. How you do this will depend on how widespread the issue is.

I found a simple example to remap a property in JavaScript, written by [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50079/jon):

```
function rename(obj, oldName, newName) {
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(oldName)) {
        return false;
    }

    obj[newName] = obj[oldName];
    delete obj[oldName];
    return true;
}
```

Source: [Rename the keys… in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942137/rename-the-keys-in-an-object#6942238)