# Escape variable name with Mustache.js

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have a csv file that I'm parsing to JSON and then sending to Mustache.js. The problem is that some of the variable names are not well formed, so I end up with objects that may look like this:

```
{
    'Num.': '1234',
    'Pass-through': 'yes'
}
```

So how would I use those variables in a Mustache template? I've tried a couple of different approaches.

```
<td>{{ Num. }}</td>
<td>{{ 'Num.' }}</td>
<td>{{ ['Num.'] }}</td>
```

But none of them work (I'd be more surprised if they did), and can't find anything in the documentation on how to escape a variable name.

Comment: maybe this question will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901683/how-do-i-reference-a-field-name-that-contains-a-dot-in-mustache-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual

> overview: |   Interpolation tags are used to integrate dynamic content
>   into the template.
>
> The tag's content MUST be a non-whitespace
>   character sequence NOT containing   the current closing delimiter.
>
> This tag's content names the data to replace the tag.  A single period
>   (`.`)   indicates that the item currently sitting atop the context
>   stack should be   used; otherwise, name resolution is as follows:
>
> 1. Split the name on periods; the first part is the name to resolve, any
>      remaining parts should be retained.
> 2. Walk the context stack from top to bottom, finding the first context
>      that is a) a hash containing the name as a key OR b) an object responding
>      to a method with the given name.
> 3. If the context is a hash, the data is the value associated with the
>      name.
> 4. If the context is an object, the data is the value returned by the
>      method with the given name.
> 5. If any name parts were retained in step 1, each should be resolved
>      against a context stack containing only the result from the former
>      resolution.  If any part fails resolution, the result should be considered
>      falsey, and should interpolate as the empty string.
>
> Data should be coerced into a string (and escaped, if appropriate) before  interpolation.

In short : you can't have element with name `'Num.'`.

Comment: Thanks. Where did you find that? Just for future reference.

Comment: Source of course. https://github.com/mustache/spec/blob/master/specs/interpolation.yml

Answer (score 0):

All variables are HTML escaped by default. If you want to return unescaped HTML, use the triple mustache: {{{name}}}.
If that doesn't work you could use a function which simply returns it's input unescaped.