# javascript: Rename the Keys of API object

Tags: javascript

I have the following data array from a API.

```
[
    {
        "barCode": "31568308949"
        "itemDesc": "ASHTON-250"
        "permPrice": 19.99
    }
]
```

And expected result as below.

```
[
    {
        "Bar Code": "31568308949"
        "Item Description": "ASHTON-250"
        "Prem Price": 19.99
    }
]
```

Could anybody help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so, you want to change what the API sends you? Or did you want to change the data once you receive it?

Comment: Well what is it you are trying to achieve

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `x.map(o=>Object.entries(o).reduce((a,[k,v])=>(a[{barCode:'Bar Code',itemDesc:'Item Description',permPrice:'Perm Price'}[k]]=v,a),{}));`

Comment: Thanks Everybody

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename the keys in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942137/rename-the-keys-in-an-object)

Answer (score 5):

If it's always these 3 fields, then simply rename them explicitly.

```js
let input = [{'barCode': '31568308949', 'itemDesc': 'ASHTON-250', 'permPrice': 19.99}];

let output = input.map(x => ({
  'Bar Code': x.barCode,
  'Item Description': x.itemDesc,
  'Prem Price': x.permPrice,
}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to create a `keyMap` where you can just add new keys and it will dynamically map any new keys you add:

```js
let keyMap = {
    barCode: "Bar Code",
    itemDesc: "Item Description",
    permPrice: "Prem Price"
};

let input = [{ "barCode": "31568308949", "itemDesc": "ASHTON-250", "permPrice": 19.99 }];

let newData = input.map(obj => {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((prev, next) => {
        if (next in keyMap) {
            prev[keyMap[next]] = obj[next];
        } else {
            prev[next] = obj[next];
        }

        return prev;
    }, {});
});

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map function and delete operator for this requirement.

```
var a = [ { "barCode": "31568308949", "itemDesc": "ASHTON-250", "permPrice": 19.99 } ];

var c = a.map(b=> {

b["Bar Code"] = b.barCode;
b["Item Description"] = b.itemDesc;
b["Prem Price"] = b.permPrice; 
delete b.barCode;
delete b.itemDesc;
delete b.permPrice;
return b;

})
console.log(c)
```

```js
var a = [ { "barCode": "31568308949", "itemDesc": "ASHTON-250", "permPrice": 19.99 } ];

var c = a.map(b=> {

b["Bar Code"] = b.barCode;
b["Item Description"] = b.itemDesc;
b["Prem Price"] = b.permPrice; 
delete b.barCode;
delete b.itemDesc;
delete b.permPrice;
return b;

})


console.log(c)
```

Comment: Thanks Hien Nguyen

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to loop thru the array. Use `Object.entries` to convert the object into a string. Make the first key capital letter and split the key buy capital letter. Join by space and use it as the ey to form the desired object,

```js
let arr = [{
  "barCode": "31568308949",
  "itemDesc": "ASHTON-250",
  "permPrice": 19.99
}]

let result = arr.map(o => {
  return Object.entries(o).reduce((c, [k, v]) => {
    let x = k[0].toUpperCase() + k.slice(1).match(/[a-z]+|[A-Z]+[a-z]*/g).join(" ");
    c[x] = v;
    return c;
  }, {});
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to change the object that you received, you could use the [map function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) in your array of data like this example below:

```
var elements = [ 
      { "barCode": "31568308949", "itemDesc": "ASHTON-250", "permPrice": 19.99 }, 
      { "barCode": "31568308950", "itemDesc": "ASH-299",    "permPrice": 29.99 } 
    ];

function convertItem(item) {
    var newItem = {'Bar Code':item.barCode,
                  'Item Description': item.itemDesc,
                  'Prem Price': item.permPrice};
    return newItem;
 }

  elements.map(converItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this in a general case you can make a regex with [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)that splits your keys and use them to create a new object:

```js
let o = { "someReallyLongKey": 1, "barCode": "31568308949", "itemDesc": "ASHTON-250", "permPrice": 19.99 }

let newObj = Object.entries(o).reduce((obj, [k, v]) => {
    let newKey = k.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2').replace(/\b\w/g, w => w.toUpperCase())
    obj[newKey] = v
    return obj
    }, {})
console.log(newObj)
```

If two regexes is a bottleneck, you may be able to combine them into a single `replace()`, but I think this is much easier to read and understand.

Comment: Thanks Mark Meyer

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use the new proposal [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) supported on newer versions of some browsers, and assuming the `keys` of the objects coming from the `API` are in [lowerCamelCase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) format, then you can do something like this:

```js
const input = [
  {
    "barCode": "31568308949",
    "itemDesc": "ASHTON-250",
    "permPrice": 19.99,
    "someOtherKey": "foo"
  }
];

let res = input.map(
    o => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(
      ([k, v]) => ([k[0].toUpperCase() + k.slice(1).replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1'), v])
    ))
);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: @amanjain You're welcome. Anyway, you can give an up-vote to those answers that where useful to you and choice the most you like as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking this down into two steps, one which converts from `lowerCamelCase` to `Upper Title Case` and one which converts the keys of an object using a function, yields code like this:

```js
const titleCase = str =>
  str.replace(/([^A-Z])([A-Z])/g, (_, x, y) =>  x + ' ' + y.toUpperCase())
     .replace(/^./, x => x.toUpperCase())

const convertKeys = (fn) => (obj) => Object.entries(obj).reduce(
  (a, [k, v]) => ({...a, [fn(k)]: v}),
  {}
)

const transform = convertKeys(titleCase)

const apiResponse = [
    {
        "barCode": "31568308949",
        "itemDesc": "ASHTON-250",
        "permPrice": 19.99
    }
]

console.log(apiResponse.map(transform))
```

Of course if it's just for those few fixed fields, it's easier just to write this explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Scott Sauyet

Answer (score 0):

this will dynamically create a new object with the new keys like renaming

```
function objectMap(source,keyMap) {
    return Object.entries(keyMap).reduce((o,[key , newKey]) => {
            o[newKey]=source[key]
            return o;},{})
}
```

as an example of using this with api

```
 keyMap = {
  "barCode":"Bar Code",
  "itemDesc": "Item Description"
  "permPrice": "Prem Price"
 }

 this.post('http://..','{}').pipe(map(result) => result.map(item) => objectMap(item,keyMap))
```

[rename js object keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747561/is-there-any-way-to-rename-js-object-keys-using-underscore-js/55615704#55615704)

Comment: Thanks @malbarmawi