# change property name

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object as follows:

```
var a = { 
 Prop1: 'test', 
 Prop2: 'test2' 
}
```

How would I change the **property name** of `Prop1` to `Prop3`?

I tried the following code but it didn't work...

```
for (var p in r){
  p.propertyName = 'Prop3';
}
```

Comment: I guess I'll be the one to say it this time. `var a = { Prop1: 'test', Prop2: 'test2' }` isn't JSON data. It's a JavaScript object literal that could be translated into JSON data if you chose to do so.

Comment: - You can use a utility to handle this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60677446/6512565

Answer (score 121, accepted):

That isn't directly possible.

You can just write

```
a.Prop3 = a.Prop1;
delete a.Prop1;
```

Comment: the `delete` function is usually frowned upon for its performance. Would not it be better to recreate an object?

Comment: @Dmitry: only ask yourself this question if you realize your app is slow because you're using delete. Also I guess creating a new object might be longer if there are lots of properties.

Comment: @user276648: Plus GC churn.

Comment: @Dmitry what are the downsides of using 'delete'?

Answer (score 35):

Another approach would be to use the proposed [property rest notation](http://sebmarkbage.github.io/ecmascript-rest-spread/) like so:

```
const {Prop1, ...otherProps} = a;
    
const newObj = {Prop3: Prop1, ...otherProps};
```

This is supported by Babel's [object rest spread transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/).

Answer (score 14):

Adding to the object rest spread solution

```
const { Prop1: Prop3, ...otherProps } = a;
const newObj = { Prop3, ...otherProps };
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is by using if():

```
for (key in a){
  if (key == "Prop1") {
    key = "Prop3";
  }
}
```

You can use strict equality `===` too, making no difference as you will use a string nevertheless