# Pass variable to Function by reference, and change value it?

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

I have a variable that I pass into a function, and return its updated value. The syntax looks very similar to:

```
var myName = 'hello all.';

FuncUpperCase(myName);

function FuncUpperCase(myName) {
     myName = myName.toUpperCase();
     return myName;
}
```

But the variable `myName` doesn't seem to be modified with the value from `toUpperCase()`.

**Note:** I don't want to write `var newName = FuncUpperCase(myName)`, because I don't like that syntax.

Comment: @Goodwine He wants a string to be in uppercase. He just didn't put his returned value in a var that's why it isn't working. This is not a duplicate of that post.

Answer (score 1):

This might answer your question:

[Pass a string by reference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308624/pass-a-string-by-reference-in-javascript)

Alternatively, pass an object and not a string.

```js
var something = {};
something.word = "word";
var allcaps = function(inp) {inp.word = inp.word.toUpperCase();};

allcaps(something);

//something.word has now been changed
alert(something.word);
```

Comment: This solution sounds more "js-ish" to me so I upvoted it

Comment: Thank you, your code is good. Now extend this problem, how can Lowercase() key object something (not key value) follow that syntax. Please help me !!!

Comment: @ĐìnhNhơnLê You should make a new question for that.

Comment: @ĐìnhNhơnLê This post answers how to change the property name on the object. You can't actually change it. Create a new property and delete the old one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483425/change-property-name

Comment: @ĐìnhNhơnLê Aslo, happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, everything is passed by value. It means that if you reassign a value for a given parameter in a function, you will not modify the value outside of the scope of the given function. Another important thing to understand, is how value to object references work: if you pass an object to a function, it is also by value that it is given, but if you access a property of this object, then the actual object will be modified outside of the function too, but NOT the value (that is to say, the value which is a reference to the object).

---

In the end you have to pass an object to your function and modify a property of it to make it persist outside.

```
function setToUpperCase(object, key) {
    object[key] = ('' + object[key]).toUpperCase();
    return object[key];
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var holder = { word: 'blah' };
setToUpperCase(holder, 'word');
console.log(holder.word); // BLAH
```

Comment: `everything is passed by value` : false, in your example `holder` is passed by reference...

Comment: No it is passed by value, as I said, it happens that the value is a reference to the object. Try to do `object = {};` it will not change the value of `object`, ever, it will change the value that was the reference to `object`.