# Change object property based on variable

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object like this

```
{"first":["first 1"],"second":["second 1","second 2"],"third":["third 1", "third 2"]}
```

I want to be able to change a property name based on a variable value. 
If the variable is "second" it should change the property second to whatever i want.
I have tried some methods...

This

```
object[theVariable] = "new second";
```

Will change the value of the property to this

```
{"first":["first 1"],"second":"new second","third":["third 1", "third 2"]}
```

And this

```
object.theVariable = "new second";
```

Will create a new property like this

```
{"first":["first 1"],"second":["second 1","second 2"],"third":["third 1", "third 2"],"theVariable":"new second"}
```

None of these methods change the property "second" to "new second" when "second" is stored in the variable "theVariable"

Desired result:

```
{"first":["first 1"],"new second":["second 1","second 2"],"third":["third 1", "third 2"]}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: @melpomene: looks like OP wants the key to be replaced

Comment: Your code does what you want, I don't see the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483425/change-property-name)

Comment: I want to edit the property name not the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to change the name of a property in your object.  This should work.

```
object.new_second = object.second;
delete object.second
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = {"first":["first 1"],"second":["second 1","second 2"],"third":["third 1", "third 2"]};

var theVariable = "new second";

obj[theVariable] = obj.second;
delete obj.second;

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: @Koiski Updated answer !

Answer (score -2):

Use property access through bracket notation:

```js
    var obj = {
      "first":["first 1"],
      "second":["second 1","second 2"],
      "third":["third 1", "third 2"]
    };
    console.log(obj);
    var propNameVariable = "second";
    obj[propNameVariable] = "new second";
    console.log(obj);
```

Comment: this does not change "second" to "new second". This just replaces the value

Comment: @Koiski - are you saying that you want the code to understand that the name of a new property is `"new " + <name of old property>`, delete the old property and set the new property?