# Javascript modify object attribute itself

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
var obj = {
  'a|a' : 1,
  'b|b' : 2
}
```

I wanted to change the `obj` to something like:

```
var obj = {
   'aa' : 1,
   'bb' : 2
}
```

where the attribute `a|a` was changed to `aa`.

Is there a way to do the same ?

Comment: Before I can answer this question in a useful fashion, what is your desired use case for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483425/change-property-name)

Comment: @DeanBrunt : I am populating a kendo grid which doesn't allow spaces or any special characters in the 'field' attribute. My server is actually translating the 'field' and 'title' attribute into a single object attribute i.e. 'a|a'. Ultimately i need to change the attribute to 'aa'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to iterate over an Object. I think the most straightforward method is using a `for..in` statement:

```
for (let key in obj) {
   console.log(key, '=>', obj[key]);
}
```

So changing the key name would involve using `String.replace` to change the key name:

```js
var obj = {
  'a|a' : 1,
  'b|b' : 2
}

let newObj = {};
for (let key in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      newObj[key.replace('|', '')] = obj[key];
   }
}

console.log(newObj);
```

If you don't want to create a new object, you could add the new key and `delete obj[key]`

```
for (let key in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      obj[key.replace('|', '')] = obj[key];
      delete obj[key];
   }
}
```

Another method would be to use `Array.reduce` over the keys/properties:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce((p, c) => {
  p[c.replace('|', '')] = obj[c];
  return p;
}, {});
```

Comment: can you explain what is the meaning of 
obj[key.replace('|', '')] = obj[key];

Comment: Sure, `key` is going to look like `"a|a"`, so `key.replace('|', '')` will yield `'aa'`. The value of `obj['a|a']` (or `obj[key]`) is 1, so this would look like `obj['aa'] = obj['a|a']` or `obj['aa'] = 1`

Comment: obj[key.replace('|', '')] creates a new key within the existing object and '= obj[c]' assigns the value of 'obj[c]' to the new key ? Is this behavior due to immutability of Strings ? Is that the reason we have to delete the old key ?

Comment: Exactly, it is creating a new key and assigning `obj[c]`'s value to it; however, it is not due to the immutability of strings, but the immutability of object properties names, which is why we have to delete the old key.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    obj[key.replace('|', '')] = obj[key];
    delete obj[key];
});
```

Simply iterate through all object keys and assign values to new key (without `|` characted), and delete the old key afterwards.

Comment: This is a great solution. I would also suggest `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` instead of `Object.keys()` to ignore enumerability...

Comment: True, will update my answer. Thanks for pointing it out, didn't know about this difference.

Comment: Well, your solution with `Object.keys()` was perfectly valid. This was just a suggestion, you did not have to edit your code. ;)

Comment: Well I think `getOwnPropertyNames` is better in this case :]

Comment: As you wish... You're the king of your answer! :P

Answer (score 2):

```
        var obj = {
            'a|a': 1,
            'b|b': 2
        }

        let keys = Object.keys(obj);
        let newObj = {};
        for (let key of keys) {
            let transformedKey = key.replace("|","") ; // transform your key
            newObj[transformedKey] = obj[key]
        }

        console.log(newObj);
```

This is fix your usecase.