# How a change the object key value?

Tags: javascript

How to change just value in object key?

Ex: I would like to update keyvalue `list_one` to anything value.

```
var ar = [
  {
    "list_one": [
      { id:1,product: 'Fortenza'}
    ]
  },
  {
    "list_two": [
      { id:4,product:'SETLIQUI'}
    ]
  }
]
```

My code:

```
var setTitleProduct = function(key="list_one",index=0) {
  Object.keys(ar[index][key])[0] = 'new value'; //I know this doesnt work
  console.log(ar[index][key]);
}
setTitleProduct("list_one",0)
```

Like this. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U9gd.png

Comment: How do you want the final array to be with the changes in key names??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483425/change-property-name

Comment: @Supercool. http://i.imgur.com/v6rTSfF.png

Comment: esascarello's link will help you. Still if you dont get then write in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var ar = [
  {
    "list_one": [
      { id:1,product: 'Fortenza'}
    ]
  },
  {
    "list_two": [
      { id:4,product:'SETLIQUI'}
    ]
  }
]

ar[0]['someValue'] = ar[0]['list_one'];
delete ar[0]['list_one'];

console.log(ar);
```