# Javascript: change object key and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object that I receive from an api, and each object's length are similarly long.
now, it does have a key `fname` and `lname` and I want it to become just `name`. I don't want to manually create an empty array and push a new one there just to change `fname` and `lname` into `name`.

Is there anyway I can achieve this without looping through the object and manually pushing it?

Comment: can you provide the dummy input data for better clarity?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key

Comment: [change property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483425/change-property-name) or [Changing the key name in an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809659/changing-the-key-name-in-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You can `destructure` the object while `mapping` it, here I have created a dummy data, let me know if this is something what you need:

```js
var array=[{id:1, fname:'Bob', lname: 'Alice', someotherkey:'key'}];
var result = array.map(({fname, lname, ...rest})=>({name:fname+' '+lname, ...rest}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Instead of adding just another answer on "how to rename a property", look for a dupe and VtC. Your approach with `.map()` and the spread syntax will most likely be part of those duplicates (see the examples in the comments below the question)