# Change key value in localStorage?

Tags: html, local-storage

I have a localStorage item named as "1" and containing "something".

I want to change the name to "2" and leave the contents intact. How can I do that?

I know that I can copy the entire contents to "2" and then delete "1" but is there any other direct method?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key

Comment: @tewathia This doesn't apply in this case, because localStorage is no common object.

Comment: In what sense? `localStorage['1']='something'; localStorage['2']=localStorage['1']; delete localStorage['1']` works just fine. So does `Object.prototype.renameProperty = function (oldName, newName) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(oldName)) {
        this[newName] = this[oldName];
        delete this[oldName];
    }
    return this;
}; localStorage.renameProperty('1','2');`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take a look at [the official specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-storage-interface).

The storage interface looks like this:

```js
interface Storage {
      readonly attribute unsigned long length;
      DOMString? key(unsigned long index);
      getter DOMString getItem(DOMString key);
      setter creator void setItem(DOMString key, DOMString value);
      deleter void removeItem(DOMString key);
      void clear();
    };
```

As you see, there is no move- or rename method. So the only way to change the key of data is by using `getItem` to get the data from the old key, `setItem` to put it to the new key and `removeItem` to remove the old key.

When you feel the frequent need to change keys, you should reconsider if the information you use as key is really suitable for the job.