# Change the name of a local-storage collection

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, local-storage

As per my new requirement I have to change the name of the local-storage collection name, which is by default set to its domain name. Is this possible? I have already searched it and didn't get anything. It is just to confirm that is this possible.
Suppose I have a domain named : http://www.example.com
then the local-storage will be created as http://www.example.com and its key value pair.
I want to change this from "http://www.example.com" to "http://www.example.com_local".

Please confirm me if it is possible anyhow. I am building an Umbraco website using MVC 4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change key value in localStorage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862054/change-key-value-in-localstorage)

Comment: @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck thanks, but my question was about changing the collection name, this answer refers to change the key name. The collection name is set to its domain name by default. I want to change its name.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not the key you want to change, but the value, then remember that `localStorage` operates on strings and only persists the value when you call `setItem`.

Keeping a reference to the original value you are setting, and changing that will not change anything in the `localStorage`. When dealing with the `localStorage` HTML5 API, then you need to re-set the value when you change it. You also need to re-set the value (and remove the old) if you change the key.

If you are using some helper API/library, then anything(almost) could be wrapped in it, making it impossible for me to help unless i know what library that is.