# AngularJS translate: change default language names

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

Before today in my app i had:

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {});

  $translateProvider.translations('ru', {});

  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

  $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
}]);
```

but now i have:

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('English', {});

  $translateProvider.translations('Russian', {});

  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('English');

  $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
}]);
```

so my language key is changed.

but!

when i open window tab with old localStorage (`en`) value - my new string are not translated, only in private browser mode, when cache is clean.

so i need somehow to check: if key is `en`, that replace it with `English`.

main trouble is that this service do not use $localStorage, but it's own solution for local storage.

how to solve it?

i have only such idea:

```
  if ($translate.storage().get() === 'en'){
    $translate.storage().set('NG_TRANSLATE_LANG_KEY', 'English');
  }
  if ($translate.storage().get() === 'ru'){
    $translate.storage().set('NG_TRANSLATE_LANG_KEY', 'Russian');
  }
```

Comment: you need to change the key by yourself ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/20862098/595152

Comment: Why not use `$localStorage` or the pure javascript API http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp ?

Comment: @Thom-x becouse!
https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Multi-Language read doc.

Comment: "it's own solution for local storage" Ok, I thought it use an alternative to $localStorage to write/read localstorage...

Comment: I just looked at the code from ``angular-translate-storage-local.js`` and I think your code is right, did you tried it?

Comment: @BettySt yes... just that i think it is not the best solution, also it is ugly(

Comment: Actually there is no senseful reason to change the  language code, specially if you think about other modules which also use the ISO standard shortterms.