# Using javascript square bracket notation to re-arrange values in object

Tags: javascript

I've got this object:

```
servicesSelected: {
  spw: {
    sku: "XYZ"
  }
}
```

I need to make it look like this:

```
servicesSelected: {
  XYZ: {
    sku: "XYZ"
  }
}
```

What I've done so far:

```
myVar = servicesSelected.spw.sku //stores "XYZ" as myVar
```

This is where I can't get it. The following doesn't work. I can't use regular dot notation because it doesn't support inserting variables, right?

```
newObject = ["servicesSelected"][myVar]sku[myVar]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Comment: ohhh... that worked. Thanks a bunch. I wasn't thinking along the lines of "renaming", but rather "re-arranging".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var newObject = new Object();
newObject["servicesSelected"][myVar]["sku"] = myVar;
```

Javascript supports object attribute querying with double square brackets, as well as dynamic generation of attributes. In this case, you can then query it with `newObject.servicesSelected[myVar].sku`.

Answer (score 0):

FYI this is the method that I ended up using:

```
myVar = servicesSelected.spw.sku // myVar is assigned "XYZ"
```

And then...

```
servicesSelected[myVar] = servicesSelected["spw"];
```

This created:

```
servicesSelected: {
  spw: {
    sku: "XYZ"
  },
  XYZ: {
    sku: "XYZ"
  }
}
```

The next step:

```
delete servicesSelected["spw"];
```

Created:

```
servicesSelected: {
  XYZ: {
    sku: "XYZ"
  }
}
```