# Changing field / property names in JSON requests and respnses in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I currently have JSON like the following (from the Australia Post developer guide):

```
"PickupDetails_v1.Header": 
{ "Common_v1.UserName": "testuser", 
"Common_v1.AccessKey": "xxxxxxxxx", 
"Common_v1.CustomerID": 123 }
```

I'd like to know what the best approach is to being able to have an object in JS without the namespaces (e.g. PickupDetails_v1) when retrieving data from the API and vice versa when sending data. Basically I'd like to be able to know the best way to be able to customize JSON property names in Angular.

For example:

```
var pickupDetails = { UserName: "testuser"; AccessKey: "xxxxxxx" }; 
$http.post(pickupDetails, "http://www.example.com/postageDetails"); // Should send the pickup details with the namespaces).

var storedPickupDetails = $http.get("http://www.example.com/postageDetails"); // Should have the same properties as pickupDetails.
```

Comment: i'm not sure what are you asking for... can you give more clarification?

Comment: Means you want only the content within "PickupDetails_v1.Header"

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key

Comment: Basically I want the property names in JavaScript to be like this:
    var pickupDetails = { "PickupDetails": { "UserName": "testUser" }}, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with interceptors.

The below example is taken from the [documentation for $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and modified slightly for brevity.

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
    // optional method
    'request': function(config) {
      // do something on success
      return config;
    },

    // optional method
    'response': function(response) {
      // do something on success
      return response;
    },
  };
});

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

The `config` and `response` objects will contain all data about requests and responses and you could hook into the `data` property of those objects and change the keys to add/remove the namespace