# How to replace the javascript object property name dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have created a JavaScript object like

```
var obj={}
var prop = {}
prop.name= "name",
prop.value = "10"
obj[old_name] = prop;
```

I need to change the `old_name` to `new_name`. I have tried

```
obj[new_name] = obj[old_name];
delete obj[old_name];
```

And it works but, the object order gets changed.

For example:

```
{"obj1":{"name:name","value:10"},"obj2":{"name:name","value:10"}}
```

If I replace `obj1` with `objone`, like this:

```
obj[objone ] = obj[obj1];
delete obj[obj1 ];
```

The object order changed to:

```
{"obj2":{"name:name","value:10"},"objone":{"name:name","value:10"}}]
```

But I need to change the property name alone and not the order, and I also try string replace but I think it is not the proper way, so please suggest me some ideas.

Comment: Objects have no order.

Comment: Why is the order a problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key

Comment: I've taken the liberty of fixing what I assume was a typo in your question (you used `pre_name` instead of `old_name` where I'm pretty sure you meant `old_name`). Also, it's "I" (capitalized), not "i" (lower case), in English, **always**.

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe of that question, @Cerbrus, because order is an important part of this one.

Comment: *\*Nods** Fair point

Comment: yes, it is a dynamically created object and i dont know whats inside and what to execute first, when i parse that, i used to assume the order and execute. @Johan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>Objects have no order. Any apparent order you see is unspecified behavior and you cannot rely on it.</s> They didn't when the question was asked, but [they do now](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys):

> 1. Let *keys* be a new empty List.
> 2. For each own property key *P* of *O* that is an integer index, in ascending numeric index order
>
>    - Add *P* as the last element of *keys*.
> 3. For each own property key *P* of *O* that is a String but is not an integer index, in property creation order
>
>    - Add *P* as the last element of *keys*.
> 4. For each own property key *P* of *O* that is a Symbol, in property creation order
>
>    - Add *P* as the last element of *keys*.
> 5. Return *keys*.

Your way of renaming the property is the only way of doing it: Creating a new one, then removing the old one. Doing that will change where it appears in the order of the object, because it was created after the previous property.

If you need order, use an array. <s>While theoretically arrays don't have order either (because [they're not really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)),</s> we have the convention that they have order, based on then numeric value of the indexes of the entries: The entry at index `0` is before the entry at index `1` and so on. (And modern JavaScript engines can and do use real arrays where possible.)

Comment: That's not the only way. You _could_ use: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObj).replace(old, new))`. (Seriously though, don't use this)

Comment: @Cerbrus: :-) The only way that doesn't completely replace the object, perhaps.

Comment: @Cerbrus No, you *couldn't.* Raw textual replacement is not equivalent with the above code because it would replace each and every occurrence of `old` with `new`. Not only in one property name. Not only in keys.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: `var old = '"myKey":', new = '"otherKey":'`. Or use a regex replace. Sure, just dumping the keys themselves in there is asking for problems. Well, more problems than using this, in the first place.