# Use function to rewrite JSON object keys?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a program and want to change the object key names in a JSON file with a function. I have already created a function that changes the keys when it is displayed via Angular, but I want to create a function that allows me to change the object key names directly in the JSON file.

Here is a sample of my JSON file ( the actual array contains over 300 entries ):

```
[
    {
        "FIELD1":"key",
        "FIELD2":"company",
        "FIELD3":"team",
        "FIELD4":"num_female_eng",
        "FIELD5":"num_eng",
        "FIELD6":"percent_female_eng",
        "FIELD7":"last_updated",
        "FIELD8":"Submit more data!",
        "FIELD9":"https://github.com/triketora/women-in-software-eng"
    },
    {
        "FIELD1":"all",
        "FIELD2":"ALL",
        "FIELD3":"N/A",
        "FIELD4":"2798",
        "FIELD5":"14810",
        "FIELD6":"18.89",
        "FIELD7":"11/18/2015",
        "FIELD8":"",
        "FIELD9":""
    },
    {
        "FIELD1":"wellsfargo",
        "FIELD2":"Wells Fargo",
        "FIELD3":"N/A",
        "FIELD4":"1296",
        "FIELD5":"5407",
        "FIELD6":"23.97",
        "FIELD7":"7/22/2015",
        "FIELD8":"",
        "FIELD9":""
    }
]
```

and what I have done thus far to change the key names:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
  .module("app.companies")
  .controller('CompaniesCtrl', CompaniesCtrl);

    CompaniesCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'CompanyFactory'];

    function CompaniesCtrl($scope, CompanyFactory) {
      $scope.work = "i work";
      $scope.companies = CompanyFactory;

      $scope.makeChart = function(company){
        $scope.femaleDevs = parseInt(company.num_female_eng);
        $scope.allDevs = parseInt(company.num_eng);
        $scope.company = company.company;
        $scope.maleDevs = $scope.allDevs - $scope.femaleDevs;
        console.log($scope.maleDevs);
      };
    }
})();
```

Thank you for all of your help :) !

Comment: Your question does not contain a question.

Comment: You want to change the content of the JSON file and you give us an Angular Code. When do you want to change the "FIELDX" name into normal names in your code ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should help you:

```
var fieldsmap = {
    'FIELD1': 'key',
    'FIELD2': 'company',
    'FIELD3': 'team',
    'FIELD4': 'num_female_eng',
    'FIELD5': 'num_eng',
    'FIELD6': 'percent_female_eng',
    'FIELD7': 'last_updated',
    'FIELD8': 'name2',
    'FIELD9': 'name3'
};

function renameObjectKeys(obj) {
    for (var key in fieldsmap) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && fieldsmap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            obj[fieldsmap[key]] = obj[key]; //copy the key into new key
            delete(obj[key]); // delete old key
        }
    }
}

myArray.forEach(function(object) {
    renameObjectKeys(object);
});
```