# Replace key in an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects :

```
arrayOfObject = [{'key1': [1,2]} , {'key2': [1,2,3]} , {'key3': [1,2,4]}]
```

I have the name of the key I want to replace in my array :

```
var keyString = 'key1';
```

And I have the new name the key should take :

```
var newKey    = 'newKey'
```

How to make my array this :

```
arrayOfObject = [{'newKey': [1,2]} , {'key2': [1,2,3]} , {'key3': [1,2,4]}]
```

[JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key) this can help me to rename the key but the thing is how to access the object first in my array that has the `key1` key.

Note that `keyString` is random. So it's pointless to get it like `arrayOfObject[0]`

https://jsfiddle.net/tcatsx6e/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this solution:

```
var arrayOfObject = [{'key1': [1,2]} , {'key2': [1,2,3]} , {'key3': [1,2,4]}];

var keyString = 'key1';
var newKey    = 'newKey';

var newArray = arrayOfObject.map(function(item) {
  if (keyString in item) {
    var mem = item[keyString];
    delete item[keyString];
    item[newKey] = mem;
  }
});
```

Please check this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/daxetoqopa/edit?js,console) for a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

This will return the index of the object you want to modify.

```
function(arr, keyString) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (arr[i][keyString] !== undefined) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}
```