# Unable to replace key for an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and I need to rename the keys.

This is my approach:

Convert array of objects to JSON, replace the key and then do a JSON.parse

Replacing the oldKey with newKey is failing as this is a array!

Here is my JSON string.

```
str "[{\"194240_0900217\":\"500\"},{\"194242_0900294\":\"600\"}]"
```

I need like this:

```
str "[{\"194240\":\"500\"},{\"194242\":\"600\"}]"
```

Is there any other better approach to achieve this?

Comment: show how did you replace those keys.Show your efforts

Comment: you have a string so you can use a regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/jV8eL1/1)

```
  var str="[{\"194240_0900217\":\"500\"},{\"194242_0900294\":\"600\"}]"
  var a=str.replace(/(_\d+)/g,"")
  console.log(a); 
// [{"194240":"500"},{"194242":"600"}]
```

a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sj293hca/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for in` loop and use either `delete` after adding a replacement property or just set the old property to `undefined` depending on your preference after reading [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/208105/691711)

```
var data = {
    "194240_0900217": "500",
    "194242_0900294": "600"
};

var k,
    matches;

console.log(data);

for (k in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        matches = k.match(/(\d+)_\d+/);
        if (matches) {
            data[matches[1]] = data[k];
            delete data[k];
        }
    }
}

console.log(data);
```

This prints:

```
{ '194240_0900217': '500', '194242_0900294': '600' }
{ '194240': '500', '194242': '600' }
```