# Javascript: how to loop and change key name?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

How can I change key name but key its values?

For instance I have this json data that I have stored:

```
{ particles: 
   { name: 'particles',
     values: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  timestamps: 
   { name: 'timestamps',
     values: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } 
}
```

And I will loop this input and change the key:

```
{ particles: 'particle', timestamps: 'timestamp' }
```

Change `particles` to `particle` and `timestamps` to `timestamp`

My attemp:

```
for (var property in data) {
   stored[data[property]] = stored[property].values;
   stored[property].name = data[property];
}
```

I only managed to change the `name`'s value inside the stored data but not the **key** name...

Any ideas?

Comment: `delete` the old property then add a new one.

Comment: Trying to generate a working solution. Care to show what is in data? a subset will be nice.

Comment: probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Answer (score 5):

Assign new property by getting old property value and then delete old property.

```js
var data = {
  particles: {
    name: 'particles',
    values: []
  },
  timestamps: {
    name: 'timestamps',
    values: []
  }
}

var newK = {
  particles: 'particle',
  timestamps: 'timestamp'
};

// get all object keys and iterate over them
Object.keys(newK).forEach(function(ele) {
  // assign object property based on old property value
  data[newK[ele]] = data[ele];
  // update name property
  data[newK[ele]].name = newK[ele];
  // delete old object property
  delete data[ele];
})

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by iterating the data and create the new keys and delete the old ones.

***E.g.***

```
var data = {
    particles: {
        name: 'particles',
        values: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
    },
    timestamps: {
        name: 'timestamps',
        values: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
    } 
};

var res = { particles: 'particle', timestamps: 'timestamp' };

for (var k in res) {
    var newValue = res[k];
    data[newValue] = data[k];
    data[newValue].name = newValue;
    delete data[k];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to remove the key using the `delete` statement after that you can add the new property using the Static method of the `Object` class using the `defineProperty` method. Here it is sample code.

```
var data={ particles: 'particle', timestamps: 'timestamp' };

for(var k in data){
    document.write(k+":"+data[k]+"<br/>");
}

if(data.hasOwnProperty("particles")){
    value=data["particles"];
    delete data["particles"];
    Object.defineProperty(data,"particle",{
        value: value,
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
    });
}

if(data.hasOwnProperty("timestamps")){
    value=data["timestamps"];
    delete data["timestamps"];
    Object.defineProperty(data,"timestamp",{
        value: value,
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
    });
}

document.write("<br/>new values <br/>");

for(var k in data){
    document.write(k+":"+data[k]+"<br/>");
}
```

Happy Coding!!!
:)

Answer (score -1):

You can convert your `Object` to a `String` using `JSON.stringify`, then replace any occurrences of `particles` or `timestamps` (`str.replace(/particles/g, "particle")`). Finally, convert your string back to an `Object` using `JSON.parse(str)`.

**NB:** to make sure that you will not alter any other data but the keys:

```
str.replace(/{"particles":{"name":"particles"/g, '{"particle":{"name":"particle"')
```