# Change object key using Object.keys ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have

```
var tab = {
abc:1,
def:40,
xyz: 50
}
```

I want to change the name of abc,def, xyz to something else, is it possible?

I tried

```
const test = Object.keys(tab).map(key => {
  if (key === 'abc') {
    return [
      a_b_c: tab[key]
    ]
  }
});

console.log(test);
```

I got many undefined keys.

Comment: Sure you do - your `map` callback only `return`s anything when `key === 'abc'`, and will return `undefined` else. What did you expect?

Comment: Actually that should throw a syntax error. Array literals don't have properties.

Comment: Is the question "How do I rename object properties?", or "How do I rename object properties *with `Object.keys()`*?" Anyway, you can't rename a property, you have to add a new property and delete the old one. Or build a new object with the key names that you want.

Comment: @nnnnnn I don;'t know, as long as it worked, I mentioned object.keys() because that's what in my mind first. Basically I want to normalize or change the object key's names.

Comment: @Bergi so what's the solution?

Comment: [Renaming object keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key). By the way, what if another property already exists with the new name?

Comment: @nnnnnn I rather build a new set of array than doing those over complicated stuff, what do you think?

Comment: @AlanJenshen So what's the expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I solved it. I used a map to map between existing key and new key. Just substitute the map with whatever new values you need. Finally remove old keys from the object using `omit`.

```
var tab = {
  abc:1,
  def:40,
  xyz: 50
}

var map = {
    abc : "newabc",
    def : "newdef",
    xyz : "newxyz"
}


_.each(tab, function(value, key) {
    key = map[key] || key;
    tab[key] = value;
});


console.log(_.omit(tab, Object.keys(map)));
```

Comment: what if u dont know the abc ,def , xyz in map?

Answer (score 19):

Here is the full code for replacing keys based on object that maps the values to replace:

```
const tab = {abc: 1, def: 40, xyz: 50};
const replacements = {'abc': 'a_b_c', 'def': 'd_e_f'};

let replacedItems = Object.keys(tab).map((key) => {
  const newKey = replacements[key] || key;
  return { [newKey] : tab[key] };
});
```

This will output an array with three objects where keys are replaced. If you want to create a new object out of them, just:

```
const newTab = replacedItems.reduce((a, b) => Object.assign({}, a, b));
```

This outputs: `{"a_b_c": 1, "d_e_f": 40, "xyz": 50}`

Comment: `Object.assign({}, ...replacedItems)` should do as well. And don't forget to pass an initial argument to `reduce`!

Answer (score 6):

#### With lodash [mapKeys](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapKeys) function its quite easy to transform object keys.

```js
let tab = {
  abc: 1,
  def: 40,
  xyz: 50
}

const map = {
  abc: "newabc",
  def: "newdef",
  xyz: "newxyz"
}

// Change keys
_.mapKeys(tab, (value, key) => {
  return map[value];
});

// -> { newabc: 1, newdef: 40, newxyz: 50 }
```

Comment: I think that it should be: return map[key]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to do it with deconstructing assignment and arrow functions.

```js
const rename = (({abc: a_b_c, ...rest}) => ({a_b_c, ...rest}))
console.log(rename({abc: 1, def: 2}))
// { "a_b_c": 1, "def": 2 }
```

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE:
**Sorry for the syntax errors; corrected and verified in browser console.**

Shortest way I've found so far:

```
let tab = {abc: 1, def: 40, xyz: 50};

const {abc: a_b_c, def: d_e_f, ...rest} = tab;
tab = {a_b_c, d_e_f, ...rest}  
// { "a_b_c": 1, "d_e_f": 40, "xyz": 50}
```

Comment: I tried this code and it doesn't work, can you provide a REPL? Thanks!

Comment: change `const tab` to `let tab`.  You didn't state the error you were getting.

Comment: It would be more beneficial to have an embedded working example. The current error when copying and pasting this code into one is:

"Unexpected token (3:14)"

Answer (score 2):

That's easy with lodash.

```
import { mapKeys } from 'lodash';    

const tab = {
    abc: 1,
    def: 40,
    xyz: 50
};

const test = mapKeys(tab, (value, key) => {
    if (key === 'abc') return 'a_b_c';
    return key;
});
```

Comment: here is the result: https://repl.it/@Man_Wai_Lorentz/WhichJuniorRobodoc

Answer (score 1):

A really easy way to change the keys dynamically without having to map the new key values could work like this :

```js
const tab = { abc: 1, def: 40, xyz: 50 };
const changeString = (s) => s.split('').join('_');

Object.entries(tab).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [changeString(k)]: v }), {})

// Output: {a_b_c: 1, d_e_f: 40, x_y_z: 50}
```

It uses `Object.entries` but you can easily swap it over to `Object.keys` like this:

```js
Object.keys(tab).reduce((acc, k) => ({ ...acc, [changeString(k)]: tab[k] }), {})
```

---

**Advanced: Nested objects**

If you have nested objects and want to cycle through all the keys, you could try this:

```js
const changeString = (s) => s.split('').join('_');
const isArray = (a) => Array.isArray(a);
const isObject = (o) => o === Object(o) && !isArray(o) && typeof o !== 'function';

const keyChanger = (o) => {
  if (isObject(o)) {
    return Object.entries(o).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [changeString(k)]: keyChanger(v) }), {})

  } else if (isArray(o)) {
    return o.map((i) => keyChanger(i));
  }

  return o;
};
```

And you call it by simply doing this:

```
const tab2 = { abc: 1, def: 40, xyz: { hij: 12, klm: [{ nop: 43 }, { qrs: 65 }]}}

keyChanger(tab2)

// Output: { a_b_c: 1, d_e_f: 40, x_y_z: { h_i_j: 12, k_l_m: [{ n_o_p: 43 }, { q_r_s: 65 }]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const countries = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Afghanistan"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Albania"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Algeria"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "American Samoa"}
];
const transformed = countries.map(({ id, name }) => ({ label: id, value: name }));
console.log(transformed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the new key and delete the old one.

```js
var tab = {
abc:1,
def:40,
xyz: 50
}

    var key = 'abc'
    console.log(key)
    tab['a_b_c'] = tab[key]
    delete tab[key]
    
 
console.log(tab);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why loop at all?

Comment: Got your, it was not needed since OP was checking for a single value, can just directly edit it. Thanks, I missed that

Answer (score 0):

you can use ES6 destructuring for it. For example, you can do something like this:

```
let sample = {a:1,b:2,c:3}
let {a:pippo,...rest} = sample
sample={pippo,...rest}
```

Answer (score -1):

hope this will help

initial data:

```
let tab = {
    abc: 1,
    def: 40,
    xyz: 50
};
```

new key mappings:

```
let newKeyMappings = {
    abc: 'cab',
    def: 'fed',
    xyz: 'zyx'
};
```

mapping values with new keys

```
let mapped = Object.keys(tab).map(oldKey=> {
    let newKey = newKeyMappings[oldKey];
    let result ={};
    result[newKey]=tab[oldKey];
    return result;
});
```

since mapped contains array of mapped object apply reduce operator

```
let result = mapped.reduce((result, item)=> {
    let key = Object.keys(item)[0];
    result[key] = item[key];
    return result;
}, {});
```