# Bad character in json response angular 2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I've retrieved a JSON response from an external API and one of the variable names begins with a # character, so the JSON variable looks like this #text. Unfortunately angular doesn't know how to handle this variable, is there any way delete the # so that the data assigned to the identifier is usable.
[image: JSON response with #text identifier]

Comment: What do you mean "angular doesn't know how to handle it?" That could mean a number of things, but what I think you mean is that _you_ don't know how to handle it. Don't use the dot notation, use the bracket notation to reference it, like `object['#text']` instead of `object.#text`

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know how to handle it, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reference a property that does not follow the rules for a properly formatted [identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier), you must use bracket notation instead of dot notation for the [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```js
var object = JSON.parse('{"#text":"https://lastfm-im...png","size":"extralarge"}')
console.log(object['#text'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you cam modifide the response - loop throw it wite map- and chenge the object key -see here:
[JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Answer (score 0):

You can use square bracket notation instead of dot notation. like (**Object mutation is highly not recommended**)

```js
//to access it u can use square bracket notation like k["objectname"]
let k = {"#test":"some data"}
 alert("data is "+k["#test"])
```