# How to rename key of object in an array

Tags: javascript

How to replace array element value with another

i have array like this, without using jquery

```
 this.products = [
      { 
        text: 'prod1', 
        value: 1 
      },
      { 
        text: 'prod2', 
        value: 2 
      },
      { 
        text: 'prod3', 
        value: 3 
      }
 ];
```

i want to replace 'text' to  'label'

Comment: `products.map(prod => { return { label: prod.text, value: prod.value }; })`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Comment: Try this `var result = products.map(({text, value}) => ({label: text, value}));`

Comment: thanks @HassanImam working perfect

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about this?

```js
var products = [{
    text: 'prod1',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    text: 'prod2',
    value: 2
  }, {
    text: 'prod3',
    value: 3
  }
];

products.forEach(function(obj) {
  obj.label = obj.text;
  delete obj.text;
});
console.log(products);
```

Answer (score 12):

using ES6:

```
const updatedProducts = products.map(({text: label, value})=>({value, label}));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
There are many ways using map in ES6



    var products = [
          { 
            text: 'prod1', 
            value: 1 
          },
          { 
            text: 'prod2', 
            value: 2 
          },
          { 
            text: 'prod3', 
            value: 3 
          }
     ];

    const newProducts = products.map(({text: label, value})=>({value, label}));
    console.log(newProducts );

    console.log("===================Another  Method====================")


    products.map((el)=>{
    el.label = el.text
    delete el.text
    })

    console.log(products);
```

Answer (score 0):

For people like me who are looking for an answer that does not mutate the original objects (which will cause errors in React) but instead want to return a new array full of new objects with only one specific key renamed in each object I have create the following function.

```js
export const renameKey = (arr, oldKey, newKey) => {
  let newArray = [];

  arr.forEach((obj) => {
    let newObj = {};
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      if (key === oldKey) {
        Object.assign(newObj,{ [newKey]: obj[oldKey] });
      } else {
        Object.assign(newObj,{ [key]: obj[key] });
      }
    });
    newArray.push(newObj);
  });

  return newArray;
};
```