# remove _ from a json using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Below, I have json from which I want to remove underscores.  Here is what I tried.

I am getting getting "replace is not a function".

```
  var y= {
                "QUESTION_MARKS": {
                                "count": 390,
                                "percentage": 8.8
                },
                "NEARLY_ACTIVATED": {
                                "count": 710,
                                "percentage": 16
                },
                "MOST_VALUBLE_SUBSCRIBERS": {
                                "count": 1650,
                                "percentage": 37.2
                },
                "LIKELY_TO_THRIVE": {
                                "count": 300,
                                "percentage": 6.8
                },
                "EMAIL_ENGAGE": {
                                "count": 420,
                                "percentage": 9.5
                },
                "EMAIL_INACTIVE": {
                                "count": 32,
                                "percentage": 0.7
                },
                "NEVER_ACTIVATED": {
                                "count": 930,
                                "percentage": 21
                }
};
    var yformatted=y.replace(/[_-]/g, " "); 
    easeSummary=yformatted;
```

Comment: `y` is not a string. It's an object.

Comment: you can try JSON.stringify to convert it to a string, remove underscores, then JSON.parse to parse it back to an object. Not sure if it will work

Answer (score 2):

You must convert your JSON object to a String, then you can use replace function to do what you are looking for

```
var yformatted=JSON.stringify(y).replace(/[_-]/g, " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

For replace to work you need to convert your object to string and then replace _. Once that it is done convert it back to object. Take a look at below snippet.

```js
var y = {
  "QUESTION_MARKS": {
    "count": 390,
    "percentage": 8.8
  },
  "NEARLY_ACTIVATED": {
    "count": 710,
    "percentage": 16
  },
  "MOST_VALUBLE_SUBSCRIBERS": {
    "count": 1650,
    "percentage": 37.2
  },
  "LIKELY_TO_THRIVE": {
    "count": 300,
    "percentage": 6.8
  },
  "EMAIL_ENGAGE": {
    "count": 420,
    "percentage": 9.5
  },
  "EMAIL_INACTIVE": {
    "count": 32,
    "percentage": 0.7
  },
  "NEVER_ACTIVATED": {
    "count": 930,
    "percentage": 21
  }
};
var yformatted = JSON.stringify(y).replace(/[_-]/g, " ");
var easeSummary = JSON.parse(yformatted);
console.log(easeSummary);
```

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle for an example of using `for(in)`: http://jsfiddle.net/craftman32/djb1m7p0/

```
 var y = {
   "QUESTION_MARKS": {
     "count": 390,
     "percentage": 8.8
   },
   "NEARLY_ACTIVATED": {
     "count": 710,
     "percentage": 16
   },
   "MOST_VALUBLE_SUBSCRIBERS": {
     "count": 1650,
     "percentage": 37.2
   },
   "LIKELY_TO_THRIVE": {
     "count": 300,
     "percentage": 6.8
   },
   "EMAIL_ENGAGE": {
     "count": 420,
     "percentage": 9.5
   },
   "EMAIL_INACTIVE": {
     "count": 32,
     "percentage": 0.7
   },
   "NEVER_ACTIVATED": {
     "count": 930,
     "percentage": 21
   }
 };

var newObject = {};

for (key in y) {
  newObject[key.replace(/[_-]/g, " ")] = y[key];
}

console.log(newObject);
```

In this example, `newObject` is created that has the same properties as `y` but with `_` removed in each property name.

Answer (score 1):

`replace` is a a method of string objects. `y` in your code is a plain object. Plain objects do not have `replace` method. You can JSON stringify the object and then use the `replace` method. This may have unwanted side effects as it seems you only want to modify the keys. I'd suggest creating a new object:

```
const x = Object.keys(y).reduce((ret, key) => {
  let nkey = key.replace(/[_-]/g, " ");
  ret[nkey] = y[key];
  return ret;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

These are a few ways to tackle this problem. Here is an other Stackoverflow link addressing this problem:
[JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45287523/1377002) SO answer as a template you could write a function to return a new object with new keys:

```js
var y = {"QUESTION_MARKS":{"count":390,"percentage":8.8},"NEARLY_ACTIVATED":{"count":710,"percentage":16},"MOST_VALUBLE_SUBSCRIBERS":{"count":1650,"percentage":37.2},"LIKELY_TO_THRIVE":{"count":300,"percentage":6.8},"EMAIL_ENGAGE":{"count":420,"percentage":9.5},"EMAIL_INACTIVE":{"count":32,"percentage":0.7},"NEVER_ACTIVATED":{"count":930,"percentage":21}};

function removeUSFromKey(obj) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    const newKey = key.replace(/_/g, '');
    return { [newKey]: obj[key] };
  });
  return Object.assign({}, ...keys);
}

console.log(removeUSFromKey(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your object in string templates because is a multi-line object and then could apply to `replace()`.

```
var y= `{
  "QUESTION_MARKS": {
                  "count": 390,
                  "percentage": 8.8
  },
  "NEARLY_ACTIVATED": {
                  "count": 710,
                  "percentage": 16
  },
  "MOST_VALUBLE_SUBSCRIBERS": {
                  "count": 1650,
                  "percentage": 37.2
  },
  "LIKELY_TO_THRIVE": {
                  "count": 300,
                  "percentage": 6.8
  },
  "EMAIL_ENGAGE": {
                  "count": 420,
                  "percentage": 9.5
  },
  "EMAIL_INACTIVE": {
                  "count": 32,
                  "percentage": 0.7
  },
  "NEVER_ACTIVATED": {
                  "count": 930,
                  "percentage": 21
  }
}`;
var yFormatted= y.replace(/_/g,' ');
```

The solved problem is here: [MissyM stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-5y2xbg)