# Method of removing / replacing the JS character from the array

Tags: javascript

How to write the **method** which at the output will convert the key where there is a character "_" into a space. At the same time, we cannot bind to shortcut keys, but to make the method universal, that would itself find and transform.

```
const arr = [{
        "name": "BMW",
        "price": "55 000",
        "color": "red",
        "constructor_man": "Billy%Zekun" //should become "constructor man"
    }, {
        "name": "MERSEDEC",
        "price": "63 000",
        "color": "blue",
        "constructor_man": "Jon%Adams" //should become "constructor man"
    }, {
        "name_car": "Lada", //should become "name car"
        "price": "93 000",
        "color": "blue",
        "constructor_man": "Bar John", //should become "constructor man"
        "door": "3"
    }, {
        "name": "TOYOTA",
        "price": "48 000",
        "color": "blue",
        "constructor_man": "Jon Hubert", //should become "constructor man"
        "door": "3",
        "max_people": "7" //should become "max people"
    }
];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Comment: You missed comas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use following approach:

```js
const arr = [{
  "name": "BMW",
  "price": "55 000",
  "color": "red",
  "constructor_man": "Billy%Zekun" //should become "constructor man"
 }, {
  "name": "MERSEDEC",
  "price": "63 000",
  "color": "blue",
  "constructor_man": "Jon%Adams" //should become "constructor man"
 }, {
  "name_car": "Lada", //should become "name car"
  "price": "93 000",
  "color": "blue",
  "constructor_man": "Bar John", //should become "constructor man"
  "door": "3"
 }, {
  "name": "TOYOTA",
  "price": "48 000",
  "color": "blue",
  "constructor_man": "Jon Hubert", //should become "constructor man"
  "door": "3",
  "max_people": "7" //should become "max people"
 }
];
const underscoreReplacer = src => src.map(item => Object.entries(item).reduce((obj,keyValue) => {obj[keyValue[0].replace('_',' ')]=keyValue[1];return obj},{}));
console.log(underscoreReplacer(arr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height:100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible not to use fromEntries, but only these methods:filter, reduce, map, 
forEach, split, join, slice, concat, find, includes, findIndex, push, keys, values, assign, splice?

Comment: Sure, but solution will be not that concise.

Comment: @LoveGIAS: just in case you might be still interrested, I've modified my code - it's still pretty neat, but much more browser independent

Answer (score 0):

You an loop through the array using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). Then loop through each object using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). If the key [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) `_`, replace with `' '`. [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) the key with `_` :

```js
const arr = [{"name":"BMW","price":"55 000","color":"red","constructor_man":"Billy%Zekun"},{"name":"MERSEDEC","price":"63 000","color":"blue","constructor_man":"Jon%Adams"},{"name_car":"Lada","price":"93 000","color":"blue","constructor_man":"Bar John","door":"3"},{"name":"TOYOTA","price":"48 000","color":"blue","constructor_man":"Jon Hubert","door":"3","max_people":"7"}];

for (let item of arr) {
  for (let key in item) {
    if (key.includes('_')) {
      item[key.replace(/_/g, ' ')] = item[key];
      delete item[key]
    }
  }
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the essence of the task is to do this task through the method

Comment: @LoveGIAS I don't understand what you're asking. Write a function with one parameter and put this `for` loop code inside it and call the function with your object?

Answer (score 0):

```
var underScoreReplacer = function(myArray){
    var temp = [];
    myArray.forEach(object => {
       var tempObj = {};
       Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
            tempObj[key.replace("_", "#")] = object[key];
       });
       temp.push(tempObj);
    });
    return temp;
}

var myArray = [
   {
    name:"BMW",
    price:"55 000", 
    color:"red",
    constructor_man:"Billy%Zekun" //should become "constructor man"
    }
];

myArray = underScoreReplacer(myArray);
console.log(myArray);
```