# How can I convert an array of objects into an array of objects with the same values but with modified keys?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array with objects and want to convert this to an array containing the same values but with different key names. (JavaScript)

For example, an array of

```js
[{name: "Bob", age: 50, person: true}, {name: "Jerry", age: 20, person: true}]
```

becomes

```js
[{identification: "Bob", years: 50, person: true}, {identification: "Jerry", years: 20, person: true}]
```

Comment: What have you tried to convert this?

Answer (score 3):

Using the Map function works perfectly here.

```
const people = [
    {name: "Bob", age: 50, person: true},
    {name: "Jerry", age: 20, person: true}
];

const formatted = people.map((person) => ({
    identification: person.name,
    years: person.age,
    person: person.person
});
```

This should work for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may use the **map** method this method returns and array with the same length as the one you are mapping:

```
 const array = [{name: "Bob", age: 50, person: true}, {name: "Jerry", age: 20, person: true}];

let newKeysArray = array.map( a => { 
   let obj = { 
        identification: person.name,
        years: person.age,
        person: person.person
   };
   return obj
 } );
```

So inside the map you are assigning the values that you need to a new object and **return** the object as the mapped item.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you prefer to modify the objects in place, you can make use of a strategy by nverba [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key):

```js
let rows = [
    {name: "Bob", age: 50, person: true}, 
    {name: "Jerry", age: 20, person: true}
];

let keyMaps = [
    ['name', 'identification'],
    ['age', 'years'],
];

for(let keyMap of keyMaps)
for(let row of rows)
    delete Object.assign(row, {[keyMap[1]]: row[keyMap[0]] })[keyMap[0]];

console.log(rows);
```

`keyMap[1]` is the new key.  `keyMap[0]` is the old key.  `Object.assign` takes the value of the old key and places it in the new key.  The `delete` keyword is confusing, but it doesn't apply to `row` as a whole.  It's only deleting the old key.