# How to rename Object Key when you have been given the function in JS

Tags: javascript, object, return, key, rename

So I have been given a question below...

```
function translateKey(student, keyToChange, translation) {  }

/*
This function will take an object representing a student's data, a key that needs changing, and its English translation.  
E.g. 
const student = {
  prénom: 'Carla',
  surname: 'Bruni',
  job: 'Artist'
}
const keyToChange = 'prénom'
const translation = 'firstName'

It returns a **new object** with the key successfully translated into English.
E.g. 
{
  firstName: 'Carla',
  surname: 'Bruni,
  job: 'Artist'
}
*/
```

I have started off with ...

```
function translateKey(student, keyToChange, translation) {

const translated = {keyToChange : translation};

const newObject = {};


// not really sure where to go from here, help please!
```

Comment: Were do you want to go? What steps have you planned?

Comment: I want to return a new object with the translated version of the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your objectif is to rename an object key you can start looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key) who has very good answers.
And you can take the answer of [ChaosPandion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4648411/10797718) as example and maybe do it like this :

```
function translateKey(student, keyToChange, translation) {
    var newObject = Object.assign({}, student);
    // Do nothing if the names are the same
    if (keyToChange === translation) {
        return newObject;
    }
    // Check for the old property name to avoid a ReferenceError in strict mode.
    if (newObject.hasOwnProperty(keyToChange)) {
        newObject[translation] = newObject[keyToChange];
        delete newObject[keyToChange];
    }
    return newObject;
}
```

If it's an exercice you had to do for a class please read the other question I linked to see others ways and try to properly understand the solution, for example why it's important to check `hasOwnProperty` or why we use `===` instead of simply `==`.

Comment: thank you BSO, but for some reason I am getting an error as I need to return a new object...
      AssertionError: expected { Object (prénom, surname, ...) } to not equal { Object (prénom, surname, ...) }

Comment: @newtojs I edited my answer, now the function return a new object :)

Comment: thank you so much I have been working on this one for the past day and got no where!!!

Comment: @newtojs Happy to help, if you think this answer solve your issue you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (old_key !== new_key) {
  Object.defineProperty(o, new_key,
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, old_key));
  delete o[old_key];
}
```

From this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14592469/9504351

Comment: I am getting the following error as i need to return a new object, any hints on how to do this please? Thanks        AssertionError: expected { Object (surname, job, ...) } to not equal { Object (surname, job, ...) }