# How to rename object property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have got a nested object. I want to rename the object properties.

```
  {
     0: {value: "can_view"},
     1: {value: "can_create"}
  }
```

My output would be:

```
  {
     user_can: "can_view",
     user_view: "can_create"
  }
```

Comment: Object keys must be unique - that output won't be valid.

Comment: I edit this . can you see

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Comment: Where are you getting those new key names from, and how do they match up with the values? They make no sense.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that in three steps:

- Get the entries using `Object.entries()`
- Use `map()` on it and replace each key with the desired value
- Convert it back to object using `Object.fromEntries()`

```js
const obj = {
  0: {value: "can_view"},
  1: {value: "can_create"}
}
const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [v.value, v.value]));
console.log(res)
```

Comment: The OP changed the output they wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Improving Maheer Ali's answer.
Here you go:

```js
const obj = {
      0: {value: "can_view"},
      1: {value: "can_create"}
    }
    var res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [v.value.replace("can", "user"), v.value]));
    
    var myResutls = JSON.stringify(res).replace(/"(\w+)"\s*:/g, '$1:');
    console.log(myResutls);
    alert(myResutls)
```

OUTPUT:

```
  {
   user_view: "can_view",
   user_create: "can_create"
  }
```

Comment: If you want to go back to JSON object then you need to do this: 
var obj = JSON.parse(myResults);