# change object key based on other object value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change object key name by comparing two objects values. if the value of second object matches the first object I want to get the key name of the second object and change the first object key name to be the same.
Here is the code I have but it fails to replace the key name of `parsedCodedParms` to `mappingParms`

```
for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(parsedCodedParams)) {
  for (var [k, v] of Object.entries(this.mappingParams)) {
    if (v.toLowerCase() == key) {
      parsedCodedParams[key] = this.mappingParams[k];
      console.log(parsedCodedParams[key])
    }
  }
}
```

Example:

```
parsedCodedParams = {a: "1",b:"2", c: "3"} 
mappingParams={ d:"1",z:"5"}
```

should result

```
parsedCodedParams= {d: "1",b:"2", c: "3"}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the inputs and desired results?

Comment: `this.mappingParams[k]` is the same as `v`.

Comment: this `parsedCodedParams[key] = this.mappingParams[k];` will replace the value not the key itself. You have to delete the previous entry and create new with new key and value.

Comment: parsedCodedParams = {a: "1",b:"2", c: "3"} mappingParams={ d:"1",z:"5"} should result parsedCodedParams= {d: "1",b:"2", c: "3"}

Comment: This can help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key

Comment: why delete? I cannot replace the key name?

Comment: No, the keys are identifiers point => to the value, not the inverse.

Comment: Keys are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the value, not the key. There's no way to replace a key directly, you have to add a new key and delete the old one.

Also, you're comparing the value with a key, not comparing the values.

```js
let parsedCodedParams = {a: "1", b:"2", c: "3"};
let mappingParams= { d:"1", z:"5"};

for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(parsedCodedParams)) {
  for (var [k, v] of Object.entries(mappingParams)) {
    if (v.toLowerCase() == value) {
      parsedCodedParams[k] = v;
      delete parsedCodedParams[key];
    }
  }
}

console.log(parsedCodedParams)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce.  Generates a map of values, merges the values as keys, discards the key and converts back to map.  Added version that preserves order of keys.

```js
parsedCodedParams = {a: "a",b:"2", c: "3"} 
mappingParams={ d:"A",z:"5"} 

// does not preserve order of parsedCodedParams
console.log(
Object.fromEntries(Object.values( // discard value as keys and convert back to map
  Object.entries(mappingParams).reduce( // merge value as keys from mappingParams
    (acc,x,k) => (acc[k=x[1].toLowerCase()] && (acc[k]=x), acc), 
    // create map of value as keys on parsedCodedParams
    Object.entries(parsedCodedParams).reduce((acc,x)=>(acc[x[1].toLowerCase()]=x,acc), {})
  )
))
);

// preserves order of parsedCodedParams
console.log(
Object.fromEntries(Object.values( // discard index i as key and convert back to map
Object.fromEntries(Object.values( // discard value as keys and convert to map with key as index i
  Object.entries(mappingParams).reduce( // merge value as keys from mappingParams (preserving index i)
    (acc,x,i,k) => (acc[k=x[1].toLowerCase()] && (acc[k][1]=x), acc), 
    // create map of value as keys on parsedCodedParams
    Object.entries(parsedCodedParams).reduce((acc,x,i)=>(acc[x[1].toLowerCase()]=[i,x],acc), {})
  )
))
))
);
```