# Remove quotations from Javascript object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

When I `console.log(row)`, the program prints:

```js
{
 'Name':'Name1',
 Age: 'Age1',
 Username: 'Username1'
}
```

How can I remove the quotations from the `Name` key? I know this may not make a difference, but with testing, I've seen it does in my program.

Any help appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Hi interesting, perhaps change the key name, `row['Name'] = row["'Name'"]; delete row["'Name'"];`

Answer (score 0):

IronMan has an answer (but they posted it in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), which is not for answers).

You will find more answers here: [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key).