# Checking to see if javascript object has the key, if it does replace it with a new key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I want to see if my object:

```
{
application: "123 abc"
description: "done"
id: 672372
issueDate: "2008-07-02T00:00:00"
}
```

has the key `description` if it does then replace the key with `information`. How can I do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const obj = {...} // => any object

if(obj.hasOwnProperty('description')) {
  obj.information = obj.description;
  delete obj.description;
}
```

Comment: what if I want to replace it with a key that has a white space in it? like "important information"?

Comment: @seyet
`obj['important information'] = "some new value."`

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

```js
var obj = {
  application: "123 abc",
  description: "done",
  id: 672372,
  issueDate: "2008-07-02T00:00:00"
}
console.log('before' + obj['application']);
if(obj['application']) {
  obj['application'] = 'new value';
}

console.log('after' + obj['application']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the destructuring and renaming the property. This will avoid mutating the current object.

```js
obj = {
  application: "123 abc",
  description: "done",
  id: 672372,
  issueDate: "2008-07-02T00:00:00",
};

const update = ({ description: information, ...rest }) =>
  Object.assign(rest, information ? { information } : {});

console.log(update(obj));

console.log(update({id: 2}));
```