# Change every key element of an JSON object in an iterative way

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have this JSON object containing moisture levels for each timestamp like the following:

```
{
  "values": {
    "21-Aug-2020 20:28:06:611591": "58.59",
    "21-Aug-2020 20:28:09:615714": "71.42",
    "21-Aug-2020 20:28:12:630856": "95.11",
    "21-Aug-2020 20:28:15:640193": "83.69",
    "22-Aug-2020 14:56:31:099964": "54.46",
    "22-Aug-2020 14:56:34:107806": "50.35",
    "22-Aug-2020 14:56:37:109768": "53.78",
    "22-Aug-2020 14:56:40:110309": "72.62"
  }
}
```

The thing is now that I want to get the first element. If the key name would be **"val1"** I could access that element by typing **ext.val1**

```
 "val1": "58.59",
```

so the question is: How can I change each key element of my object (dictionary) in an iterative way so I can access them easily?

This is my goal object modification:

```
{
  "values": {
    "val1": "58.59",
    "val2": "71.42",
    "val3": "95.11",
    "val4": "83.69",
    "val5": "54.46",
    "val6": "50.35",
    "val7": "53.78",
    "val8": "72.62"
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have an order of the keys?

Comment: `ext` is a promise.

Comment: `ext.val1` will not work. Imagine: if that were possible you would have a result *now* that is only available in some *future*. `ext` is not what you think. It is a promise object. You must embrace anynchronous programming.

Comment: the only order is that the keys values pairs are sorted time-wise based on the timestamps. I want to change the key name for each value pair in the same order.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yea it is but I have stored that I a variable so it is an object whenever I want to use it.

Comment: @Molda yea I think it could work for me

Comment: @NinaScholz has provided a similar answer also I am checking

Comment: [Edit] your question to show how you'll be getting the data from `ext` when you want to use it. There are many questions about renaming keys, including [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4647817/215552)

Comment: @trincot I just realized that .. I will edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get a new object by getting the values.

```js
const data = {
  "values": {
    "21-Aug-2020 20:28:06:611591": "58.59",
    "21-Aug-2020 20:28:09:615714": "71.42",
    "21-Aug-2020 20:28:12:630856": "95.11",
    "21-Aug-2020 20:28:15:640193": "83.69",
    "22-Aug-2020 14:56:31:099964": "54.46",
    "22-Aug-2020 14:56:34:107806": "50.35",
    "22-Aug-2020 14:56:37:109768": "53.78",
    "22-Aug-2020 14:56:40:110309": "72.62"
  }
}

data.values = Object.fromEntries(Object.values(data.values).map((v, i) => ['val' + (i + 1), v]));

console.log(data);
```

Comment: I think this may work for my case. I am trying sth out. Probably I will modify my object in this way.