# How to change object key in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object like

```
{Text Field 1: {fieldName: "Text Field 1", fieldType: "text", data: "custom value"},
Text Field 2: {fieldName: "Text Field 3", fieldType: "text", data: "new value "},
Text Field 3: {fieldName: "test kuyans 2", fieldType: "dropdown", value: Array(2), data: "value"}
```

I want to change it keys

`Text Field 1` , `Text Field 2`, `Text Field 3` to `string 1`, `string 2`, `string 3`.

Final result will be

```
{string 1: {fieldName: "Text Field 1", fieldType: "text", data: "custom value"},
string 2: {fieldName: "Text Field 3", fieldType: "text", data: "new value "},
string 3: {fieldName: "test kuyans 2", fieldType: "dropdown", value: Array(2), data: "value"}
```

Could someone please help me how to resolve this issue .

Thanks

**code**

```
Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(JSON.parse(item.optional_fields)).map(([key, value]) =>
      // Modify key here
      [`${headerProjectFloor[index]}`, value]
    )
  )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please share your code and specify which part of your code didn't work for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key check this

Comment: Do you want to mutate the object or create a new object with different keys? Also: Why is this tagged with `reactjs`?

Comment: I just edited my question and have added my code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using array reduce method you can do that,

```
var res = Object.keys(obj).reduce((prev, curr, index) => { return {...prev, ['string '+(index+1)]: obj[curr]}}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj['string 1'] = obj['Text Field 1']; // Assign new key 
delete obj['Text Field 1']; // Delete old key
```