# How to use variables in the first value of a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

In short I have this JSON configuration that looks like this:

```
{
    "Users" : {
        "182723618273612" : 15,
        "AddedUser" : 1
    }
}
```

I created the field through a JavaScript function, but Im trying to figure out how I can change the name of "AddedUser". I do NOT want t o change the value (1), I just want to change "AddedUser" to be another ID.

It should look like this:

```
{
    "Users" : {
        "182723618273612" : 15,
        "693582876127862" : 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript object?

Comment: You basically add a new key `693582876127862` with value `1` and remove the key `AddedUser`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Comment: What's the context? If the JSON shouldn't have a field `"AddedUser"`, why did you create it this way?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the followig:

```
const users = JSON.parse(json);

const newKey = "693582876127862";

users[newKey] = users['AddedUser']; // with this, you can use variable as a key

delete users['AddedUser'];

JSON.stringify(users);
```

Comment: This almost works, except `users` would be an object with a `users` property. --- Try `const { Users: users } = JSON.parse(json);` instead?