# JavaScript: slice object name

Tags: javascript, json, object

```
"course_DxhYTv2copzWyBhKo" : {
    "interest" : "DxhYTv2copzWyBhKo",
    "type" : "course",
    "affinity" : 3
}
```

From Object Name "course_DxhYTv2copzWyBhKo",
I want to slice "DxhYTv2copzWyBhKo"

Comment: yes it is possible :3

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Comment: have you tried to do any research? even by using your title as search string...

Comment: @LelioFaieta I have tried searching but i got object slice instead of object name slice

Comment: that's because it is called key and not name...

Comment: @LelioFaieta I also searched by key but i got answer of objects inner keys not Object Main Name key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
const data = {
  "course_DxhYTv2copzWyBhKo" : {
    "interest" : "DxhYTv2copzWyBhKo",
    "type" : "course",
    "affinity" : 3
  }
};

const key = Object.keys(data)[0];
const sliceAfterSubStr = "course_";

const slicedSubStr = key.split(sliceAfterSubStr)[1];

console.log(slicedSubStr);
```

Using [`String#substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```js
const data = {
  "course_DxhYTv2copzWyBhKo" : {
    "interest" : "DxhYTv2copzWyBhKo",
    "type" : "course",
    "affinity" : 3
  }
};

const key = Object.keys(data)[0];
const sliceAfterSubStr = "course_";
const sliceIndex = key.indexOf(sliceAfterSubStr);

const slicedSubStr = sliceIndex !== -1
  ? key.substr( sliceIndex + sliceAfterSubStr.length )
  : undefined;

console.log(slicedSubStr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `split` operation on a string. Take a look at the following code snippet.

```js
const courses = {
  "course_DxhYTv2copzWyBhKo": {
    "interest": "DxhYTv2copzWyBhKo",
    "type": "course",
    "affinity": 3
  },
  "course_DSdasdnDASnoiddDs": {
    "interest": "DSdasdnDASnoiddDs",
    "type": "course",
    "affinity": 3
  }
}

console.log(Object.keys(courses).map(key => key.split("_")[1]))
```