# How to rename key of object?

Tags: javascript

I have this :

```
  for (const key of Object.keys(filter)) {

}
```

Problem is that sometimes i get key with suffix _1, and than i have:

```
keyName_1{
  prop:'prop1'
}
```

And when i call service this keyName_1 is a problem, so what i want is always to replace this keyName1.
I tried this :

```
for (const key of Object.keys(filter)) {
      if(key.includes('_1')){

        key.replace('_1','');
      }
  }
```

But then i lose object values of that key, so my prop does not exists anymore. Is there any option to change only key name?.

Comment: This might be the answer to your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key

Comment: `key.replace('_1','');` is not going to alter the key in the object. That is just changing the string and you do nothing with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign the value to a new key and delete the old one.

```js
let o = {
  keyName_1: {
    prop: 'prop1'
  }
};
for (const key of Object.keys(o)) {
  if (key.includes('_1')) {
    o[key.replace('_1','')] = o[key];
    delete o[key];
  }
}
console.log(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mutate your source object you can do it with this syntax.

```
delete Object.assign(o, {[nextKey]: o[prevKey] })[prevKey];
```

In case if you want to create new object, you can use below syntax.

```
const newObject = {};
delete Object.assign(newObject, o, {[nextKey]: o[prevKey] })[prevKey];
```