# How to change the key which is inside an Object: JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

```
let object1 = { "hello" : [5, 12, 8, 130, 44], "hello1" : [7, 12, 8, 130, 44]};

const oldKey = "hello";
const newKey = "hello4;
const index = Object.keys(object1).findIndex(e => e === oldKey);
Object.keys(object1)[index] = newKey;

console.log(object1);
```

The key is not changing here for some reason.

Comment: you can't change a key like that

Comment: How do I do it then?

Comment: Hang on, I'm writing an answer :p

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key) is what you're looking for

Comment: @SowmenRahman - won't work with a `const`

Comment: @ponury-kostek won't work with a `const`

Comment: That does answer my question but the index of that key: value is changing and I don't want that. Since, the index is changing the position of that key: value is also changing inside an object

Comment: the index of the key is irrelevant and has no meaning, ever - never rely on the order of object keys

Comment: @dummy - presented an answer if you use `let` (or `var` for that matter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin by setting new key value to old key

then delete the old key

```js
const object1 = { "hello" : [5, 12, 8, 130, 44], "hello1" : [7, 12, 8, 130, 44]};

const oldKey = "hello";
const newKey = "hello4";
object1[newKey]=object1[oldKey];
delete object1[oldKey];

console.log(object1);
```

edit: now that you changed from `const object1` to `let object1` there is another way!!

```js
let object1 = { "hello" : [5, 12, 8, 130, 44], "hello1" : [7, 12, 8, 130, 44]};

const oldKey = "hello";
const newKey = "hello4";
object1 = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object1).map(([k, v]) => [k === oldKey ? newKey : k, v]))
console.log(object1);
```

Comment: It is working, but is it possible to only edit the key instead of assigning the values to the new key and delete the previous one?

Comment: @dummy - not for a `const` - why do you have something against `delete`?

Comment: Sry, const was my mistake in here, I have changed it. Problem still remains

Comment: what problem? you want to use let, then use the duplicates given in your question

Comment: see edit for solution now that you use `let` @dummy