# How to update JSON keys in place?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I would like to add a set of escaped quote around all first level keys in a JSON object.

```
const j = '{"a": "b", "c": "d"}';
let obj = JSON.parse(j);

Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
  k = `\"${k}\"`;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
```

which of course gives

```
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": "d"
}
```

as I need to do the substitution in the actual object.

But how can I update the keys in place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Comment: Personally, I like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58974459/215552) the best, as it is more like your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Just define a new key and give it the same value as the old key, then delete the old key.

```js
const j = '{"a": "b", "c": "d"}';
let obj = JSON.parse(j);

Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
 obj[`\"${k}\"`] = obj[k];
 delete obj[k];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
```

Comment: This could overwrite existing keys assuming the following object: `{'a':'b', '"a"':'c'}`