# How we can replace the keys of an Object with new key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object like below

```
[
  {
   "day"  : "monday",
   "value": 1
   },
  {
   "day"  : "tuesday",
   "value": 2
   },
   ...
]
```

Is there any native javascript way to replace the key with a new key. Here I need to replace the "day" & "value" with "x" & "y" respectively. (like below)

```
[
  {
   "x"  : "monday",
   "y": 1
   },
  {
   "x"  : "tuesday",
   "y": 2
   },
   ...
]
```

Comment: Object properties can be added and removed, but not really renamed... although the value can be assigned to a different property.

Comment: You cannot change property names. You can add new properties and delete old ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Comment: One basic approach could be to use `Object.entries` and then map all the properties and then do `Object.fromEntries` to get a *new* object.  Is that usable or does it have to be the same object?  (Because it's feasible to delete all properties of the old object and add in all the new properties if absolutely necessary, but I suspect it's likely not necessary.)

Comment: You are trying to [map an array onto another array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Simplest way `arr.map(o => ({x: o.day, y: o.value}))`

Comment: Using the [solution from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45287523/227299), this can be made generic. `const propMap = {day: 'x', value: 'y'}; const output = arr.map(o => renameKeys(o, propMap))`

Comment: Thanks @JuanMendes, that solves my query.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed. I believe its clear.

Comment: @ManuJ It's clear but you have not shown an attempt. We can't tell which part you're having difficulty with. Questions without an attempt will always be closed because answers will just do the work for you instead of answering a real programming question that is helpful to others, which is the point of SO, it's not just help one person at a time. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, a [search for `rename object keys javascript`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rename+object+keys+javascript) would have at least got you started

Answer (score 1):

you can use map and inside the call back create a new object and  modify it as required. Then return this object

```js
const data = [{
    "day": "monday",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "day": "tuesday",
    "value": 2
  }
];

const newData = data.map((item) => {
  const obj = {};
  for (let keys in item) {
    if (keys === 'day') {
      obj['x'] = item[keys]
    }
    if (keys === 'value') {
      obj['y'] = item[keys]
    }


  };
  return obj
});
console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Bugs me that `keys` is plural.  Also I'd create a map `m = {day:"x", value: "y"}` and then do `obj[m[key]] = item[key]`

Comment: Bugs me too, could be a lot simpler, see my comments.