# Rename Key in JS Object with values from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to rename the keys in the object with the names of the array

```js
let title = [
    'Total Cryptocurrencies',
    'Total Markets',
    'Total Exchanges',
    'Total Market Cap',
    'Total 24h Volume', 
];

var obj = {
    1: 5,
    2: 7,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0,
};
```

So in the end I want to have my object like this:

```js
var obj = {
    'Total Cryptocurrencies': 5,
    'Total Markets': 7,
    'Total Exchanges': 0,
    'Total Market Cap': 0,
    'Total 24h Volume': 0,
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Comment: Also, you can't guarantee the sort order of object properties when you iterate over them, so how would you know which array element matches the right object key?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: The code is only putting "" on the key and not renaming it with the names of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a `for` loop as follows.

```
let title = [
    'Total Cryptocurrencies',
    'Total Markets',
    'Total Exchanges',
    'Total Market Cap',
    'Total 24h Volume', 
];

var obj = {
    1: 5,
    2: 7,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0,
};

var newObj = {};

for(i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
    newObj[title[i]] = obj[(i+1).toString()];
}

var obj = newObj;
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if it the best solution but you can try

`obj= title.reduce((prev, curr, idx) => {return {...prev, [curr]: obj[idx+1]} }, {});`

Assuming obj's keys will be numbers will map perfectly with the title indexes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).