# How to update a certain field in object using the Nodejs Request Patch while keeping the others as before

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, request, patch

I have a `API` which returns the JSON data something like this:

```
{
  "data":{
    "id": "859545",
    "name":"Batman",
    "custom-fields": {
      "--f-09":"custom-1",
      "--f-10":"custom-2",
      "--f-11":"custom-3"
    },
    "tags": [],
    "created-at": "2021-09-10T15:45:16Z",
    "updated-at": "2022-04-23T11:52:49Z"
  }
}
```

For this JSON I would like to change the field "--f-09" to "custom-1, custom-new" and "--f-10" to "custom-2, custom-new" while keeping all other fields as before.

I am aware that I can use `request.PATCH` in `Nodejs` for this but in that case, I need to provide all the data again for the request which I would like to avoid. I just want to update certain fields while keeping others as before.

In this example, I have provided a simple example which contains only certain fields but in my real code I have many fields so does this mean that I need to build the `response body json` using all the fields again and just change the `--f-09` and `--f-10`?

Following is the code:

```
const jsonBody = {
  "data": {
    "id": "859545",
    "name": "Batman",
    "custom-fields": {
      "--f-09": "custom-1, custom-new",
      "--f-10": "custom-2, custom-new",
      "--f-11": "custom-2"
    },
    "tags": [],
    "created-at": "2021-09-10T15:45:16Z",
    "updated-at": "2022-04-23T11:52:49Z"
  }
}


request.patch('https://reqres.in/api/users',jsonBody,function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
        console.log(response.statusCode);
    }
  }
);
```

Does this mean that I need to build the complete JSON body again here just like I have built the `jsonBody` above while using the PATCH or is there any other way where I can just pass the value for `--f-09 and --f-10`?

Comment: _I am aware that I can use `request.PATCH` in `Nodejs`..._ are you also aware that you can parse the json, and simply change the fields with code? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key

Answer (score 0):

First you check, what parameters do you want update is side the object. then you can filter , that values only. then you can merge separate parts in the object.