# How to rename multidimensional array keys in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

im trying to rename the keys of this array:

```
'oldname': [
       {"name": "cat", "category": "animal"}
       ,{"name": "dog", "category": "animal"}
       ,{"name": "pig", "category": "animal"}
           ],
 'oldname1': [
       {"name": "pikachu", "category": "pokemon"}
       ,{"name": "Arbok", "category": "pokemon"}
       ,{"name": "Eevee", "category": "pokemon"}
             ]
```

i tried with this code:

```
        const obj = {oldKey: Object.values(result)};

        delete Object.assign(results, {newname: obj.oldKey})['oldname'];

        console.log(result);
```

but I'm doing it wrong because we dont need to effect the value, it should be something like this:

```
  'newname': [
       {"name": "cat", "category": "animal"}
       ,{"name": "dog", "category": "animal"}
       ,{"name": "pig", "category": "animal"}
           ],
  'newname1': [
       {"name": "pikachu", "category": "pokemon"}
       ,{"name": "Arbok", "category": "pokemon"}
       ,{"name": "Eevee", "category": "pokemon"}
             ]
```

is there any better way to do it using javascript?

Comment: That's not JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Comment: you should simplify the question and delete the word "array" since the question is about the keys and it's irrelevant the values are a array, and might confuse people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to create a new variable/array you can use a `for..of` loop and `Object.entries()` as follows:

```js
const
input = { 'oldname': [ {"name": "cat", "category": "animal"} ,{"name": "dog", "category": "animal"} ,{"name": "pig", "category": "animal"} ], 'oldname1': [ {"name": "pikachu", "category": "pokemon"} ,{"name": "Arbok", "category": "pokemon"} ,{"name": "Eevee", "category": "pokemon"} ] },
mapping = {'oldname':'newname','oldname1':'newname1'};

for(let [key,value] of Object.entries(input)) {
    input[mapping[key]] = value;
    delete input[key];
}

console.log( input );
```

Otherwise you can do it as follows:

```js
const
input = { 'oldname': [ {"name": "cat", "category": "animal"} ,{"name": "dog", "category": "animal"} ,{"name": "pig", "category": "animal"} ], 'oldname1': [ {"name": "pikachu", "category": "pokemon"} ,{"name": "Arbok", "category": "pokemon"} ,{"name": "Eevee", "category": "pokemon"} ] },
mapping = {'oldname':'newname','oldname1':'newname1','oldname2':'newname2','oldnamen':'newnamen'},

output = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(mapping).map(([oldname,newname]) => [newname, input[oldname]])
    .filter(([,value]) => value)
);

console.log( input );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries` to do that

```js
const replaceKeys = (data, mapping) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => [mapping[k] || k, v])
  )
  
const data1 = {
 oldName1: 1,
 oldName2: 2,
 anotherKey: 3
}

const mapping = {
  oldName1: 'newName1',
  oldName2: 'newName2'
}

console.log(replaceKeys(data1, mapping))
```