# Redefine object properties keys starting with prefix

Tags: javascript

If I have the following object, how can I redefine the keys to remove the prefix "Class"?

```
{ 
    ClassName: "John",
    ClassEmail: "john@doe.com",
    ClassPhone: "1234567"
}
```

so it becomes

```
{ 
    Name: "John",
    Email: "john@doe.com",
    Phone: "1234567"
}
```

Is there any easy way?

Comment: Are you able to please show what you've tried and what isn't working with your attempt?

Comment: You can use this answer from the dupe [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58974459) but use `.replaceAll()` for the key (or `.replace()` with a global regular expression)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
  ClassName: "John",
  ClassEmail: "john@doe.com",
  ClassPhone: "1234567"
}

const newObj = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, item) => ({ ...acc,
  [item[0].replace(/Class/g, "")]: item[1]
}), {})

console.log(newObj)
```