# How to change key name in javascript object using object dsctructing syntax?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have this object in javascript :

```
const obj={key:1,name:'abc'}
```

Now i want to change the object as following :
result : {newKey:1,name:'abc'}
How can i achieve this using Object destructuring syntax in javascript.

Comment: Please be specific. What do you mean by "change the object"?

Comment: `const {key: newKey, name}={key:1,name:'abc'}` wont change the object but u can now refer the key as newKey

Comment: See this answer: [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53753534) for a destructuring method

Comment: InSync - I want to get new object as provided in the result