# Update multiple property name in array of objects

Tags: javascript

Here is what my object looks like:

```
let myObj = {
  "Accounts": [
    {
      "Type": "Card",
      "CreditCard": {}
    },
    {
      "Type": "ACH",
      "CreditCard": {}
    },
    {
      "Type": "CDA",
      "Checking": {}
    },
    {
      "Type": "INTL",
      "Mortgage": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to change the property name from `CreditCard,Checking,Mortgage` to something common such as `FinanceRecord`. I know I can do something like below

```
let temp = myObj.map(({ CreditCard: FinanceRecord, ...item }) => ({
              FinanceRecord,
              ...item,
            }));
// Specify each property name...
myObj.map(({ Checking: FinanceRecord, ...item }) => ({
                  FinanceRecord,
                  ...item,
                }));
```

Is there any better way to do this? I have about 20 different property names which I want to update. Thanks!

Edit:

Expected Output:

```
let myObj = {
      "Accounts": [
        {
          "Type": "Card",
          "FinanceRecord": {}
        },
        {
          "Type": "ACH",
          "FinanceRecord": {}
        },
        {
          "Type": "CDA",
          "FinanceRecord": {}
        },
        {
          "Type": "INTL",
          "FinanceRecord": {}
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Don't use destructuring and ellipsis. Loop over the properties, and test if it's your list of names you want to replace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Comment: your question is confusing, you want to do an update and your code do duplicates copy (with  changing names)

Comment: @MikePerrenoud: I know how to change the single property key. I am just looking for a way to do this dynamically for multiple property keys.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a more concise way to achieve this using the `Object.entries()` and `Array.map()` methods. Here's how you can update all the properties named CreditCard, Checking, and Mortgage to FinanceRecord:

```
let myObj = {
  "Accounts": [
    {
      "Type": "Card",
      "CreditCard": {}
    },
    {
      "Type": "ACH",
      "CreditCard": {}
    },
    {
      "Type": "CDA",
      "Checking": {}
    },
    {
      "Type": "INTL",
      "Mortgage": {}
    }
  ]
}

myObj.Accounts = myObj.Accounts.map(account => {
  const updatedRecord = {}
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(account)) {
    updatedRecord[key === 'CreditCard' || key === 'Checking' || key === 'Mortgage' ? 'FinanceRecord' : key] = value
  }
  return updatedRecord
})
```

In the above code, `Object.entries(account)` returns an array of key-value pairs for each property of the current account object. We then loop through each key-value pair using a `for...of` loop, and check if the key is one of the property names we want to update. If it is, we update the key to "FinanceRecord" in the `updatedRecord` object. If it's not, we leave the key as is. Finally, we return the `updatedRecord` object for each account using the `Array.map()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Type` of the item specifies what the other property name will be, then you can use a map to do "dynamic destructuring"

```js
let myObj = {
  "Accounts": [
    { "Type": "Card", "CreditCard": {} },
    { "Type": "ACH", "CreditCard": {} },
    { "Type": "CDA", "Checking": {} },
    { "Type": "INTL", "Mortgage": {} }
  ]
}

const typeProperty = {
  Card: "CreditCard",
  ACH: "CreditCard",
  CDA: "Checking",
  INTL: "Mortgage"
}

const temp = myObj.Accounts.map(({
  Type,
  [typeProperty[Type]]:FinanceRecord,
  ...rest
}) => ({
    ...rest,
    Type,
    FinanceRecord
}));

console.log( temp );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without any destructuring (and therefore without making whole new objects) by adding the desired new property name and then deleting the old one:

```
function update(obj, nameMap) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(p {
    if (p[0] in nameMap) {
      obj[nameMap[p[0]] = p[1];
      delete obj[p[0]];
    }
  }
}
```

Then:

```
update(myObj.Accounts, {
  CreditCard: "FinanceRecord",
  Checking: "FinanceRecord",
  Mortgage: "FinanceRecord"
});
```

Now in the interest of full disclosure, deleting properties probably blows away per-object internal optimizations that the runtime has done before that point. Well, maybe it does.