# Accessing and editing nested object keys in JavaScript through path

Tags: javascript, json, path, lodash, jsonpath

I want to access and edit a **nested ** key in the object (not the value but the key itself).

eg;

```
{
  "name": {
    "firstname": "Boba",
    "lastName": "Fett"
  }
}
```

For example I want to edit the name.firstname field to FullName as shown below;

```
{
  "name": {
    "FullName": "Boba",
    "lastName": "Fett"
  }
}
```

Using lodash, tried unsetting the key value pair and setting a new pair with the key changed but this will add the new pair to the end of the json, i want to preserve the order of the json.

Also note that the key may be nested several levels deep and i have the path to the key.
Are there any other libraries or other ways i can do this instead of using a recursive loop?

Im using JavaScript.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: FYI I've updated your question as the data structure you have is an object, not JSON.

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of [javascript-object-rename-key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4647817/383904) ? What have you tried? Any code to share?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Its similar but i want to preserve the order of the object, the added key should be at the same position it was before

Comment: `preserve the order of the object` is irrelevant with an object to be honest

Comment: @JaromandaX    Yes.. but this is used as a json so the edited key should be in the same place it was originally in

Comment: then edit it in JSON

Comment: @JaromandaX Wht do u mean?

Comment: JSON does ***not*** require, nor have any significance for the order of the keys.

Comment: `the edited key should be in the same place` order isn’t guaranteed in js objects.  Sounds like you should use an array of field names if you want them to appear in a certain order.

Comment: `const x = JSON.stringify(data).replaceAll('"firstname":', '"FullName":');` - now your JSON has `FullName` instead of `firstname`

Comment: `Object.entries.map`  followed by `Object.fromEntries` should do it -and- preserve order.

Comment: but if that object, you did say you have an object, is called `data` ... then you can simply `data.name=Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data.name).map(([k,v])=>[{firstname:"FullName"}[k]??k,v]));`

Comment: @James there is a defined order as of ES6. [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219) However, it's still not a good idea to try on rely on it staying the same. Serialising/deserialising an object or changing a key or passing the object through some code that manipulates it (e.g., sanitisation, validation, etc) can disturb that order. Among many other situations. Especially ones that might come in the future, not right now. And if you rely on an order, you might be surprised.

Comment: @VLAZ I will continue to use arrays of field names (object property names) to guarantee the correct order.  I’m not convinced either way by the linked question.

Comment: @James the order of enumeration is defined in the spec which is nearing being a decade old now. If you find some environment which does not use this enumeration order, then it's not ES6 compliant. As I said, though, you should not rely on that order.

Comment: @JaromandaX    But my object will have several nested objects and each may be nested several levels deep so can't use map, I have the json path to the key, can't I use it to edit the key in some way?

Comment: Yes you can, but you also arbitrarily don't want to change the order of the keys in the object for no reasons at all ... I did suggest an alternative using string replaceAll on the JSON string

Comment: @JaromandaX  Using replaceAll will replace every instance but there may be many instances of the same key nested somewhere else so it cant be used:(

Comment: @JaromandaX    Also i want to access the key through the path as there may be copies of the same key nested somewhere else

Comment: @SalmanA  But my object will have several nested objects and each may be nested several levels deep so can't use map as it maps only the top level

Comment: @GevinHasmitha if you have the path then use it to locate that particular object and replace it with the copy e.g. `foo.bar.baz.person = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(foo.bar.baz.person).map(...))`.

Comment: @SalmanA  Yea thats the thing im not clear on how to do cus then how will the order be preserved, won't the copy just be added to the end of the object?